What could even be an error when loading a pickled file in Python?
The pickled file is voc_final.pkl, in the source code used in the paper GAMENet.
I tried to load it:
import dill
voc = dill.load(open("voc_final.pkl", 'rb'))

But got the error:
TypeError: code expected at least 16 arguments, got 15

That's weird because even if the pickled file contains an unknown class in another library, which is not available in my computer. The loading of the pickled file should be fine. I tested this scenario as:
Writing pickle:
import dill

class XYZ():
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.x = i
        self.y = {}
    
    def do_something(k):
        return k + 10

p = XYZ(10)

with open('test.pkl','wb') as output:
    dill.dump(obj={"aaa": p}, file=output)

Loading pickle in another Python session:
import dill
with open('test.pkl','rb') as input:
    kkk = dill.load(input)

This works just fine!
I wonder what could be possibly an error when loading a pickled file? Of course, not trivial error like "file not found", "file being used", etc.
Maybe because of different Python version as here said: "There is also no guarantee of compatibility between different versions of Python because not every Python data structure can be serialized by the module."?
Reproducibility

Windows 10 x64
Python 3.11.7


It's true that this is due to different Python versions (mine: 3.11.7, the original author's: 3.6).
I checked their Jupyter Notebook and found they were using Anaconda with Python 3.6. I created the same environment (Python 3.6) and could load the pickled file:
import dill
voc = dill.load(open("voc_final.pkl", 'rb'))

The output:
{'diag_voc': <__main__.Voc at 0x7fb058f14d68>,
'med_voc': <__main__.Voc at 0x7fb058ecce80>,
'pro_voc': <__main__.Voc at 0x7fb058edd0b8>}

It would be great if any published Python source code includes requirements.txt.
The pickle load is supposed to detect the right protocol to load. But in my case, it simply failed!

The protocol version of the pickle is detected automatically, so no protocol argument is needed.

